# Batch Reg Query is adding unexpected blank lines to output file

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am running a batch file that checks a number of registry files using the "reg query" command. I have it set up to send an error message to an error log (ErrorLog.txt), and also tell the user to check the error log in the main results text file (REGValues.txt). The problem is that I get these, seemingly random, blank lines throughout REGValues.txt file. How do I keep it from inserting these blank lines?

Here is a segment of my code, just past where it usually adds to blank lines.

```
 mkdir c:\temp2\
SET dirname=c:\temp2\
SET filename2=REGValues.txt
SET errlog=ErrorLog.txt

:_registryValues
@echo Scanning Registry Values

@echo HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\LegalNoticeText 1>>       %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" /v LegalNoticeText /z 1>> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 1 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%

@echo HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\LegalNoticeCaption 1>> %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" /v   LegalNoticeCaption /z>> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 1 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%

@echo HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultPassword 1>> %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\" /v DefaultPassword /z >> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 1 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%

@echo HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\AdditionalBaseNamedObjectsProtectionMode 1>> %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\" /v AdditionalBaseNamedObjectsProtectionMode /z >> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 0 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%

@echo HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\EnablePortLocking 1>> %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\ /v EnablePortLocking /z >> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 1 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%

@echo HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\EnhancedSecurityLevel 1>> %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\" /v EnhancedSecurityLevel /z >> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 1 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%

@echo HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters\LDAPServerIntegrity 1>> %dirname%/%errlog%
reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters\ /v LDAPServerIntegrity /z >> %dirname%\%filename2% 2>> %dirname%\%errlog%
if errorLevel 1 echo Check Error Log 1>> %dirname%\%filename2%
```

Here is what the text file looks like that I am sending the results too:

```
Check Error Log 
Check Error Log 
Check Error Log 
Check Error Log 


Check Error Log 
Check Error Log
```

It prints out my error log just fine:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\LegalNoticeText 
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\LegalNoticeCaption 
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultPassword 
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\AdditionalBaseNamedObjectsProtectionMode 
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters\EnablePortLocking 
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\EnhancedSecurityLevel 
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Comment: What Windows version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8, but it also occurs on Windows 7...I think I figured it out. I thought you only needed double quotes if there was a space in the Registry Value I was searching for, but the values that do not have double quotes are where I'm getting the blank lines.

Comment: Double quoting everything wasn't the solution, but I narrowed the problem down to: it happens at the keys that do not have a double quote "" around the key. I tried adding it but then it just says the key isn't found, even when it previously was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still don't know why, I found a solution by taking a different approach. Instead of trying to figure out why the arbitrary blank lines where in the file, I decided to find a way to remove the lines after the file was created.

I used this command (placed at the very end of my batch file) to remove the blank lines.

```
@echo Cleaning File

For /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%RegValues.txt%) Do Echo %%A >> %RegValues_Clean.txt%

@echo Finished Cleaning File
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check very carefully.

First matter : Keyname should `NOT` terminate `\` - I use W7 and get different results `\`-terminal vs no-`\`-terminal

Second matter : `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager) is ALWAYS true. `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is true if `errorlevel` is n **OR GREATER THAN n**

Third matter: `1>>` - the `1` is redundant (matter of style - or perhaps you enjoy typing?)

Fourth: `@echo on` at the start of the script turns `echo`ing of the batch code off. Further `@echos` are then redundant - `echo` will suffice.

Now - paradoxically, you'll find that removing the terminal `\` from the keys will produce `MORE` empty lines. `req query` outputs a well   spaced   report with heaps of whitespace. The value reported is introduced with a newline and terminated with another - or so it seems...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I am going to stick with the script to remove blank lines. I will however apply some of your suggestions about redundancy. I am working with a program that my coworker started so I kept everything inline with what was already in the file, but this will help clean it up a lot!